# Apache vhost not loading proper site

Tags: apache, vhosts

So i've got 2 websites hosted on my server, with to separate domain addresses.   Site1 is my personal site, Site2 is a buisness site....My vhost config is as such

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@Site1.com
    ServerName Site1
    ServerAlias Site1
    DocumentRoot "F:/some/folder"
    ErrorDocument 302 /?error=302
    ErrorDocument 403 /?error=403
    ErrorDocument 404 /?error=404
    ErrorDocument 500 /?error=500

<Directory "F:/some/folder">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>

ServerSignature on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@site2.com
    ServerName Site2
    ServerAlias Site2
    DocumentRoot "F:/someother/folder"
    ErrorDocument 302 /?error=302
    ErrorDocument 403 /?error=403
    ErrorDocument 404 /?error=404
    ErrorDocument 500 /?error=500

<Directory "F:/someother/folder">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>
ServerSignature on
</VirtualHost>
```

now my problem is, regardless of which website URL i enter,  it goes to only Site1.   If i add the NameVirtualHost *:80 line, I get an arror from Aapche stating:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

so what happens if you change

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Tried that,  says that there are overlapping ports, and that first site takes precedence